# How to get the first string of each of the data inside a String array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

If I have a string array `String[] array = new String[3];` , how do I get the first characters of each of the data inside that array and store in a new string array `String[] newarray = new String[3];`

For example:

```
array[0] = AB;
array[1] = AB;
array[2] = AB;
array[3] = AB;
```

I must get all 4 letter "A" because it is the first character in each of the data inside my String[].

So it must be like this:

```
newarray[0] = first character of array[0] //which is "A"
newarray[1] = first character of array[1] //which is "A"
newarray[2] = first character of array[2] //which is "A"
newarray[3] = first character of array[3] //which is "A"
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you tried? It's something you can find pretty easily, so I assume you have some troubles with the code you wrote.

Comment: After understanding that a string is just an array of character, you can get the first character using newarray[1] = array[1][0];

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I've asked this because tesseract.getText(); gives me result of a single character(which is the correct one) and puts a "newline" after the character. So instead of array[x] = "A" it turns into array[x] = "A" + newline or nextline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var newArray = array.Select(r=> r[0].ToString()).ToArray();
```

This assuming that you don't have `null` or empty string `""` in any of your array element. If there are `null` or empty strings in your array element and you want to ignore those in the final result you can do:

```
var newArray = array
            .Where(r=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r))
            .Select(r => r[0].ToString())
            .ToArray();
```

if you want to consider any white space as empty string then you can replace `string.IsNullOrEmpty` with `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` (supported with .Net framework 4.0 or higher)

Comment: My problem is getting the first character of each of the data inside a String array. Not getting the first data inside the string array.

Comment: @julianconcepcion, try that code, it would return first character of each data element. It will not return you the first array element

Comment: Can I do this `array[0][0].toString()` ?

Comment: @julianconcepcion, yes you can, string itself is treated as array of characters,